# How to get a list of all elements in a scroll-able table

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am attempting to get a list of all elements within a certain class in a table using puppeteer so I can iterate over all of them. Thing is, the table is dynamically loaded when scrolling, so elements will appear/disappear from DOM depending on how far you've scrolled.

Using a simple $$ query does not work and returns the incorrect number of elements, simply what is visible on the page already.

```
async getAllElements() {
    const elms = await this._page.$$('td.class');
    return elms;
}
```

I expect the query to give me all possible elements on the page, but because of the scrolling implementation I am only getting the elements currently visible on the page.

Comment: can you provide the url you are trying to scrape or the relative code?

Comment: If your app needs to scroll to load more, puppeteer won't magically do it unless you tell it to, what are you trying to test?

Comment: I am trying to test that a certain number of elements are present in a table via UI, but the table has to scroll down to load things. I know you can scroll with puppeteer, but the elements in the page disappear from the top and get replaced when scrolling on the page. So I expect ~40 elements to be present in a table but the most I am able to get right now is 22.

Comment: I remember a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56065061/5627599) where the page used JSON to download the data into a lazy-loading table. It might be easier to go for that resource instead of extracting the data from the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured out my own answer.

To get every element in the list, regardless of whether or not it has appeared in DOM yet, use the following:

```
await page.$eval('#myTableSelector', e => {
    //Do something with e.items
});
```

While this does not return an array of ElementHandles as I had hoped, it does allow me to get all the information I might need, just as if I was using the console in Dev Tools.